# Change Workbook links to New WorkBook VBA [Excel]

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a Macro that creates a new workbook and copies over a number of worksheets. Lets say we have the following worksheets:

```
Names
Times
Lists
```

When pressing a the macro on the original workbook I want these work sheets copied over which I currently do perfectly fine. However, I don't understand how to make the links in these sheets refer to the new workbook rather than the original.

Code tried:

```
    Sub WorkBook_Test()
        Dim wbO As Workbook, wbN As Workbook
    
        Set wbO = ActiveWorkbook
        Set wbN = Workbooks.Add
    
        wbO.Sheets("Names").Copy wbN.Sheets(1)
        wbO.Sheets("Times").Copy wbN.Sheets(2)
        wbO.Sheets("Lists").Copy wbN.Sheets(3)
    
End Sub
```

Problem:

The Lists sheet on the new workbook still refers to =[OrginalFile.xlsm]Names!B27 for example. However I would like all links to refer to the current workbook rather than the original file.

Note: I have some pretty in depth if statements for formulas so have multiple references that all refer to the original file when I would like the links to just reference the current files worksheets.

Comment: Hi, James!

I agree when you copy to a new workbook the formulas stay referencing the Original File.
But once you want to create a full copy of sheets, why don't you just SaveAs and so delete the another sheets out of these 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over [LinkSources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.LinkSources) and use the [ChangeLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.ChangeLink) method.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WorkBook_Test()

    Dim wbO As Workbook, wbN As Workbook

    Set wbO = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbN = Workbooks.Add

    wbO.Sheets("Names").Copy wbN.Sheets(1)
    wbO.Sheets("Times").Copy wbN.Sheets(2)
    wbO.Sheets("Lists").Copy wbN.Sheets(3)
    
    Dim ar, n As Integer
    With wbN
        ar = .LinkSources(1) 'xlExcelLinks
        If Not IsEmpty(ar) Then
            For n = 1 To UBound(ar)
                .ChangeLink Name:=ar(n), _
                    NewName:=.Name, Type:=xlExcelLinks
                'Debug.Print n, ar(n)
            Next
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```